# Incentives to experimentally confirm theories after tons of experiments with various perspectives have already been run

Tags: experimental-physics

It appears throughout history that the glory goes towards who proposes a theory and outlines the math behind it, the first person to experimentally test it, but not all the hundreds of experiments afterwards.

For the first group, there is a great incentive. For the 2nd or 3rd groups, who may have started around the same time but weren't done when the 1st group published, the incentives are still there. Scientists continue coming up with different ways to test the theory and publishing papers, life goes on great. But at some point you have too much evidence and yet people keep adding to the pile.

For example, special relativity has been tested by hundreds of experiments and is continuously tested everyday by satellites orbiting Earth. Is there any reason for someone to have added the 201st paper on the topic? I guess not, but someone did. Why are those papers published then?

On a related note, the 2nd or 3rd confirmation is still doing a great service. However, does the scientist behind it ever feel bad no one (except their colleagues) remembers their name, only the person who invented the theory and perhaps the first tester?

Comment: Does the nightingale care about the audience?  A creative physicist creates the theories or experiments for his/her enjoyment of physics, and it is enough that  the peer review accepts the contribution as rigorous and useful at that state of research.  Fame is irrelevant to the action, imo.

Comment: Newtonian gravity was done at the time of Newton, right? And then somebody measured the orbit of Mercury with high precision and Einstein had to come up with general relativity. And that was the end of it, right? Yes, it was, right until some folks discovered dark matter. Now we are either going to find dark matter fields and gravity stays the same or we need a completely new theory of gravity. Isn't science cool?

Comment: A lot of us don't care if anybody remembers our names. I'm just grateful to be paid to pursue my hobby ツ

Comment: One incentive is that they could be the ones who finally measure a deviation, which unearths the next great theory.

Comment: "Physics is like sex: sure, it may give some practical results, but that's not why we do it." —Richard Feynman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, those "confirmatory" tests are performed over time as experimental techniques get better and enable greater accuracy- so the experimental team gets to narrow down the uncertainty in the original numbers, and perhaps add another significant digit to one of those measured numbers.

Furthermore, it is an indication of new physics at work when a number measured in an experiment begins to diverge from the one predicted by a model after a few significant digits. For example, although the gyromagnetic ratio was set by Dirac's electron model at exactly 2, the experimental value is 2.002319... with the difference being due to (tiny, but measurable) corrections arising from quantum field theory, which were not included in the Dirac picture. In another example, the *Lamb shift* (a tiny difference in energy between two electronic energy levels experimentally measured in the hydrogen atom) was not predicted by the Dirac equation, according to which those energy states should have been exactly equal. This difference was also an indication of new physics arising again from quantum field theory.

These examples furnish a strong motivation to push ahead with new, more accurate measurements of old numbers.

Finally, imagine that a completely new technique is invented by which one of these "old numbers" can be experimentally measured, and imagine further that the new test confirms the old number. This means that any shortcomings which might have been lurking in the original experiment can be ruled out, bolstering confidence in the original technique and the number it measured.

Comment: ..and the new technique (which was shown to agree with existing physics) could be used to measure something else (which might not have been reliably measured).

Comment: @robphy, yes yes, that is a beneficial side effect.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with anna v in the comments, and I would also add the following.

I think it seems to you that there is a significant, wasted effort to reconfirm things that have already been shown. But how in-detail have you understood what was being tested? Maybe the experimentalists are just looking at the subject with a finer eye to detail. For example, you mentioned that special relativity has been tested often enough. But there is, in reality, no such thing as "testing special relativity" as a whole. One can only do very specific experiments to test particular phenomena. And if you would assume that, having tested (say) 50 phenomena across a moderate range of parameters is sufficient evidence that *any* phenomena across any regime should be "just fine" as well, I would beg to differ.

In truth, it has happened many times historically that a theory was thought of as more generally valid than it actually was - not because of some obvious failure but because of a special case that had not been (or not been able to be) tested. The fact that there is at times less motivation to test for less "exciting" results is actually unfortunate and I am very thankful for the reproducibility that physics usually has.

Of course, it can (and does) happen that fully duplicate work is done. This is not a tragedy either, and is often intentional - for example ATLAS and CMS both independently found the Higgs at the LHC. If this were re-done 100 times with the same level of rigor, I agree that it would be a bad use of funding, but I would be surprised to find many instances of this in the literature.

Comment: ATLAS and CMS have different design and they don't perform exactly the same over the full energy range and for different event types. This was done on purpose. See http://www.particles.uni-freiburg.de/dateien/vorlesungsdateien/wpf2hadroncollider/kap2c for a comparison of specs and performance. LHC also has special detectors like LHCb for b quark physics and ALICE for ion collisions that would not be possible with either ATLAS or CMS.

Comment: @FlatterMann Thanks for pointing that out. It is the case that they were intended to be able to both independently reach some of the same results, and they have differences as a result of that independence of design. But it seems like you are saying there were some intentional pre-planned differences as well. That seems reasonable.